# How do i update a document's specific property based on a condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection called conversation, and the document looks like this:

```
{
   _id: "1",
   userOneId: "11",
   userOneName: "User One Name",

   userTwoId: "22",
   userTwoName: "User TwoName",

   lastMessage: {
       senderName: "User Two Name",
       message: "rrrr"
   }
}
```

What i want to do is finding a document which
"userOneId" is equal to "someId" or "userTwoId" is equal to "someId"

**conditions are:**

**if "userOneId" is equal to "someId"**

```
 if userOneName is equal to lastMessage.senderName is true
       update both lastMessage.senderName and userOneName to "newUserName"

 if userOneName is equal to lastMessage.senderName is false
       update only userOneName to "newUserName"
```

or

**if "userTwoId" is equal to "someId"**

```
 if userTwoName is equal to lastMessage.senderName is true
       update both lastMessage.senderName and userTwoName to "newUserName"

 if userTwoName is equal to lastMessage.senderName is false
       update only userTwoName to "newUserName"
```

its impossible that the both condition will be true.

my sample query is this: (still dont know how to conditionally update a specific property)

```
conversationModel.updateMany(
          {
               $or: [
                        { userOneId: currentUserId },
                        { userTwoId: currentUserId },
               ]
           },

           {
               /*
                   insert conditionally update a specific property here
               */
           }
)
```

Comment: what is your mongoDB version ?

Comment: im using mongodb atlas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that's what you're looking for (if you want to proceed with 1 query):

```
db.getCollection('conversations').update({
    $or: [
        { userOneId: currentUserId },
        { userTwoId: currentUserId },
    ]
}, [{
    $set: {
        "lastMessage.sender": { $cond: [{ $or: [{ $eq: ["$userOneName", "$lastMessage.sender"] }, { $eq: ["$userTwoName", "$lastMessage.sender"] }] }, "newUserName", "$lastMessage.sender"] },
        "userOneName": { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$userOneId", currentUserId ] }, "newUserName", "$userOneName"] },
        "userTwoName": { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$userTwoId", currentUserId ] }, "newUserName", "$userTwoName"] }
    }
}], { multi: true });
```

**Explanation**:

- We use `.update` method as it supports an [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/method/db.collection.update/index.html#update-method-agg-pipeline)
  as second (update) parameter;
- According to the update rules in your question `$set` operator contains some rules to update 3 fields:

  `lastMessage.sender` when its value equals to either value of `userOneName` or value of `userTwoName`, then the value for update is "newUserName", otherwise the old value is used;

  `userOneName` when value of `userOneId` equals to value of `currentUserId`, then the value for update is "newUserName", otherwise the old value is used;

  `userTwoName` when value of `userTwoId` equals to value of `currentUserId`, then the value for update is "newUserName", otherwise the old value is used;
- `$cond` operators contain the rules of the following structure: [*expression*, *valueIfTrue*, *valueIfFalse*];
- `multi: true` option is provided to update multiple documents

Comment: there you go :)